# How to use json and php

Tags: php, json, web

I'm new to JSON, but I have experience in PHP. Can someone explain to me how JSON works, especially with PHP, and EASY way would be nice.

EX: I have a php array like:

```
array(
    array('id' => 1, 'img' => "http.img1.png", 'title' => 'ice cream'),
    array('id' => 2, 'img' => "http.img2.png", 'title' => 'silly snail'),
    array('id' => 3, 'img' => "http.img3.png", 'title' => 'big bear'),
    array('id' => 4, 'img' => "http.img4.png", 'title' => 'Funny cat'),
);
```

is this fine, or should I alter this array? I want to convert this to a JSON Object. In the php array should there be a parent, and do I have to assign array elements as children, or can each php obj be it's own JSON obj? Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the json?

Comment: create a JSON object, what else can you do with it?

Comment: structure of the array depends on how you want the result to be, there is no standard on that..

Comment: All that matters is that the structure of the array matches what the application that you're sending to expects. If you're implementing the other application as well, you can do whatever you want. json_encode() will encode the entire struction, you don't have to encode pieces separately (if you do, the receiver will also have to decode them separately, and somehow know whether a string should be treated as a raw string or as JSON to decode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run json_encode on the variable that you want to turn into a json string.

```
$something = array("test" => array("value", "another value", 4));
echo json_encode($something)
```

This will produce

```
{"test":["value","another value",4]}
```

Also, putting that string into `$something = json_decode("{"test":["value","another value",4]}");` will produce back the same array that was passed into `json_encode`.

Note that JSON is not a programming language; it is a way to represent objects. http://json.org has a complete visual representation of how to use it. JSON's main components are Arrays (surrounded by []) and Objects (surrounded by {}). Arrays are lists of comma separated values (see json.org for how to tell it the types...its pretty simple) while objects are key:value pairs separated by commas between each pair where they key is a string surrounded by quotation marks. Above I created an Object with a key called "test" whose value was an Array with two strings and a number in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use json_encode() for encoding the array, get the array back by using json_decode().